# сохранить в базе mysql dd.mm.yyyy на yyyy-mm-dd php

Tags: php, mysql, дата, insert

Здравствуйте Азы, помогите начинающему программисту сделать функцию с сохранением даты в MYSQL.
Дело такое, у пользователя есть форма, в котором он вводит дату dd.mm.yyyy.
но в базе mysql есть поле date. Оно хранит запись в обратном формате yyyy-mm-dd
как мне корректно сохранить введенную пользователем запись в базу?

Comment: что значит "поле в базе хранит дату в таком то формате" ? У вас поле в БД действительно типа char/varchar в котром дата в текстовом виде или все таки типа date ?

Comment: А может лучше unixtime в базе, а средствами PHP вводить/выводить в любом виде, хоть в индивидуальном для каждого пользователя?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте функцию [STR_TO_DATE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)

```
INSERT ... STR_TO_DATE(value, '%d.%m.%Y'), ...
```